# Wordpress theme with fullpage.js

Tags: wordpress, themes, fullpage.js

I'm developing webpage which should have Wordpress backend. I'm coder, but I've never developed Wordpress template.

Do you know any theme based on fullpage.js, which I can modify ... and learn from it ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in the fullPage.js website and its docs, [here's one](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/utils/wordpress.html) you can use. From Themify.

You might find another one at the [resources section of the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#resources).